# Git rebase 2 commits shared by 2 branches

Tags: git

my current git branch model is:

```
                       C6 - C7 [branch B]
                      /
C1 - C2 - C3 - C4 - C5 [branch A]
```

all commits are on my local pc. 
I'd like to squash C1 into C2 without change my repository branches model.
If I checkout [branch A] and squash C1 and C2 then [branch b] has already existing C1 and C2 commit (not the C2' squashed commit).
What's the right way to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you have rebased interactively `branchA`, you would need to rebase `B` on top of (the new) `A`:

```
                       C6 - C7 [branch B]
                      /
C1 - C2 - C3 - C4 - C5

C12 - C3' - C4' - C5' [branch A] 

git checkout branchB
git rebase branchA

                      C6' - C7' [branch B]
                     /
C12 - C3' - C4' - C5' [branch A]
```